# How do you enforce minimum size of a collection in JPA or Hibernate

Tags: json, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, bean-validation

With an @Entity class containing a field:

```
@JsonProperty("arrays")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "systemID", nullable = true)
private List<PVArray> arrays = null;
```

That defines a collection.  The next step is to enforce that `arrays` must have one or more entries.

The system is being developed with Spring Boot, using Jackson for JSON serializing/deserializing, and Hibernate and JPA for persistence.

I think a constraint like this has to be enforced manually.  I haven't found any annotation describing this constraint.  Manual enforcement in the setter doesn't seem sufficient - what if the incoming JSON simply does not have an `arrays` field?  The setter would never be called and no chance for enforcement.

Is it possible to write a method that's called after the JSON is deserialized?  Or more generally (because obviously the classes are instantiated other ways besides deserializing JSON), a method that's called at the end of instantiating the object, so that object constraints can be enforced?

I have other constraints to consider than just the size of certain collections.  For example one class can have only one of its fields set, not both.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html

Comment: This is not jpa, which simply persists what you have. Java bean validation api is what you need. Update the question and tags

Comment: Thank you for the pointer -- yet another kitchen sink to learn.  I'll be able to try @Size in a couple days.

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this:

```
@Size(min=1, max=10)
@JsonProperty("arrays")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "systemID", nullable = true)
private List<PVArray> arrays;
```

With size you are saying that at least you need from 1 to 10 elements